# Servlet with jsp is not working

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, jetty

I am using embedded Jetty server with JSP and JSTL support, but this shouldn't matter.

This is what I am trying to do:

- I want to access page http:localhost:8080/admin/index.jsp
- When I access this page a servlet "StatisticsServlet" must create and send a map
  to index.jsp
- index.jsp has to loop through the map and show keys and values.

This what I have so far:

**StatisticsServlet.java**

```
public class StatisticsServlet extends HttpServlet {

    SingletonStatsContainer stats = SingletonStatsContainer.getInstance();

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        Map<String, Integer> requestListLenghts = stats.getItemsInUnprocessedRedisList();

        req.setAttribute("stats", requestListLenghts);
        RequestDispatcher reqDispatcher = req.getRequestDispatcher("/index.jsp"); //Is this correct?
        reqDispatcher.forward(req, resp);
    }

}
```

This is what starts the server:

**AdminWeb.java**

```
public class AdminWeb implements Runnable {
    private static final ContextHandlerCollection webContext = new ContextHandlerCollection();
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AdminWeb.class);
    @Override
    public void run() {
        logger.info("Starting Jetty server . . .");
        WebAppContext webAppContext = new WebAppContext();
        webAppContext.setDescriptor(webAppContext + "/WEB-INF/web.xml");
        webAppContext.setResourceBase("src/com/company/web/");
        webAppContext.setContextPath("/admin");
        webAppContext.addServlet(StatisticsServlet.class, "/admin");
        webContext.setHandlers(new Handler[]{webAppContext});
        JettyServer server = new JettyServer();
        server.setHandler(webContext);
        try {
            server.start();
            logger.info("Server started! Admin page now accessible @ http://localhost:{}/admin", server.getRunningPort());
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            logger.error("Server not started : {}", ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

And the index.jsp itself:

```
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<%@ page import="com.company.web.StatisticsServlet"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>

    <body>        
        <c:forEach items="${stats}" var="entry">
            ${entry.key}", ${entry.value}
        </c:forEach>
    </body>
</html>
```

Any help is appreciated!
NOTE: I am not using any web.xml configuration. If possible then add web.xml example according to this scenario as well.

Thank you!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Figured it out myself. If somebody is facing the same problem an example can be found here: https://github.com/lkallas/embedded-jetty-jsp-jstl